# Optimization in C++ (Object Declaration)

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

This is a sample pseudo-code:

```
vector A;
void function1()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        vector B;
        read a file and populate B;
        do some operation on B;
        add contents of B to A; 
    }
}
```

Is this code performance/memory optimized? If not, can someone please point in the right direction?

Comment: What does "performance/memory optimized" mean? In the classic sense, there is a tradeoff between memory and performance. Which one do you care more about? And what kind of performance threshold do you need? There is nowhere near enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While I care the most about the performance, I am doing this on a large scale (with different objects), and I am running out of memory. So I am trying figure out places where I am wasting memory. My main question is about initialization of B. Would I be creating 100 different instances of B in this sample case?

Comment: @azgard B is constructed and deconstructed in every iteration, so no, you aren't creating 100 instances of B but efficitvely you are recreating it in every iteration. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector `B` needs to reallocate in every loop. It may be better to have a fixed vector `B` that you once reserve with enough capacity forever and only `clear()` during the loop:

```
std::vector<T> B;
B.reserve(/* biggest size you need */);

for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
{
    // read into B

    A.insert(A.end(),
             std::make_move_iterator(B.begin()),
             std::make_move_iterator(B.end()));

    B.clear();
}
```

Instead of `A.insert` you can also try:

```
A.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
std::move(B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(A));
```

This has different exception guarantees. Use whichever is most appropriate for your requirements.

If you know the entire size of all append operations, you can also `reserve` enough capacity in `A` upfront to avoid reallocations.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out. If B were to be very large, would the clear command be slower than reallocation? Is there a way to deallocate in such a case?

Comment: @azgard `clear()` will be faster, as it doesn't reallocate the storage. However in both cases the dtor of every element will be called.

Comment: Yes, you can reallocate the vector like this: `B.swap(vector<T>())`. It will be slower than clear.

Comment: @PeterK: That would entirely defeat the purpose of my answer. If you want that behaviour, use the OP's original code.

Comment: I've never seen a 3-argument use of `std::move` before. That's likely to confuse people into thinking `std::move` does more than turn something into an rvalue